# Why does it get "undefined method `videoId'" sometimes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to load the search result of Youtube with using its API.
It looks working fine so far but it sometimes get this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `videoId' for #<Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::ResourceId:0x000000072afcb8>):
```

I'm just wondering if YouTube won't provide its videoId sometimes under some  particular situation?

How can I avoid this problem?

**CONTROLLER**

```
. 
.
.
@search_response = client.execute!(
  :api_method => youtube.search.list,
  :parameters => {
    :part => 'snippet',
    :q => 'cat',
    :maxResults => 10,
    :order => 'date',
    :pageToken => pageToken
  }
)
.
.
.
```

**VIEW**

```
<% @search_response.data.items.each do |video| %>
    ID: <%= video.id.videoId %><br />
    Title: <%= video.snippet.title %><br />
    Description: <%= video.snippet.description %><br />
    <img src="<%= video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url %>" with="480" height="360"><br />
    <br />
    <br />
<% end %>


<%= debug @search_response.data.items %>
```

**Output of debug**

```
- !ruby/object:Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult
  data:
    kind: youtube#searchResult
    etag: ! '"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/RtuotxAng6F5sgkBlbg_LTSDi7s"'
    id:
      kind: youtube#video
      videoId: d5TsLsjtth8
    snippet:
      publishedAt: '2015-06-29T04:19:43.000Z'
      channelId: UCxdQj_S7w5O9lEm6v2uH_EA
      title: ! '◕‿◕☞ Funny Cats   Funny Cat Videos   Funny Cat Vine   Most Funny Cat
        2016  #2'
      description: funny vines clean version funny vines compilation 2015 new funny
        vines christian delgrosso funny vines cartoon voice overs funny fails dirt
        bike funny fails don't ...
      thumbnails:
        default:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d5TsLsjtth8/default.jpg
        medium:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d5TsLsjtth8/mqdefault.jpg
        high:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d5TsLsjtth8/hqdefault.jpg
      channelTitle: ''
      liveBroadcastContent: none
- !ruby/object:Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult
  data:
    kind: youtube#searchResult
    etag: ! '"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/wXXxhJIuGlDPCjNyD6fxNnnp9yA"'
    id:
      kind: youtube#video
      videoId: 812W82_VDaA
    snippet:
      publishedAt: '2015-06-29T03:57:38.000Z'
      channelId: UCH9ev60cc7IFU_fqhBEpChw
      title: ! 'The Cat, the Vagabond and the Victim: A Cats in Trouble'
      description: ! 'The Cat, the Vagabond and the Victim: A Cats in Trouble http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00U259982?tag=weiradlaemm06-21
        Feature * Heir of the cat... When ...'
      thumbnails:
        default:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/812W82_VDaA/default.jpg
        medium:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/812W82_VDaA/mqdefault.jpg
        high:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/812W82_VDaA/hqdefault.jpg
      channelTitle: ''
      liveBroadcastContent: none
- !ruby/object:Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult
  data:
    kind: youtube#searchResult
    etag: ! '"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/QWxRfjhIEHs95Rw1BSFjPwamYVY"'
    id:
      kind: youtube#video
      videoId: 4c2OvbRT1ZQ
    snippet:
      publishedAt: '2015-06-29T03:51:47.000Z'
      channelId: UCvrbFkZE2CXP8SVK3w5XS4A
      title: ネコのケンカ?  - cat fight? -
      description: 諦めなければいつかは叶うｗ.
      thumbnails:
        default:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4c2OvbRT1ZQ/default.jpg
        medium:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4c2OvbRT1ZQ/mqdefault.jpg
        high:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4c2OvbRT1ZQ/hqdefault.jpg
      channelTitle: ''
      liveBroadcastContent: none
- !ruby/object:Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult
  data:
    kind: youtube#searchResult
    etag: ! '"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/Ezf1iUMSd4dY_5GJ7Rb0MxDaJcI"'
    id:
      kind: youtube#video
      videoId: -n040rD3nxI
    snippet:
      publishedAt: '2015-06-29T02:40:30.000Z'
      channelId: UCsukgxUI8Gkju1lKCOKBlcQ
      title: Funny Cat Joke
      description: King of shitty 10 second videos.
      thumbnails:
        default:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-n040rD3nxI/default.jpg
        medium:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-n040rD3nxI/mqdefault.jpg
        high:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-n040rD3nxI/hqdefault.jpg
      channelTitle: realchris1Returns
      liveBroadcastContent: none
- !ruby/object:Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult
  data:
    kind: youtube#searchResult
    etag: ! '"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/TNpAkcwloC58Xi8aCVsmSXMspyA"'
    id:
      kind: youtube#video
      videoId: e5LJvFUM9k4
    snippet:
      publishedAt: '2015-06-29T02:40:12.000Z'
      channelId: UC64ta8zKaK5gXWPgTk37VNA
      title: ! 'Sam & Cat Season 1 : FULL Episode 1 - 36 FREE STREAMING HD QUALITY'
      description: ! 'Sam & Cat - Season 1 : Episode 1 - 36 FULL STREAMING , Visit
        Link On List All Episode http://youtube.vg/HVDX3KE8 And Enjoyed For 720p Until
        1280p High ...'
      thumbnails:
        default:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e5LJvFUM9k4/default.jpg
        medium:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e5LJvFUM9k4/mqdefault.jpg
        high:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e5LJvFUM9k4/hqdefault.jpg
      channelTitle: ''
      liveBroadcastContent: none
- !ruby/object:Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult
  data:
    kind: youtube#searchResult
    etag: ! '"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/HcqCoYiw3qvNoxloToHL_LeyAk4"'
    id:
      kind: youtube#video
      videoId: x4RB5oF72AU
    snippet:
      publishedAt: '2015-06-29T02:07:49.000Z'
      channelId: UCFPV7m24Y-KM66v_aScWTRQ
      title: Kucing Berani serang Ular ( cat vs snake )
      description: Kucing Berani serang Ular ( cat vs snake )
      thumbnails:
        default:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/x4RB5oF72AU/default.jpg
        medium:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/x4RB5oF72AU/mqdefault.jpg
        high:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/x4RB5oF72AU/hqdefault.jpg
      channelTitle: ''
      liveBroadcastContent: none
- !ruby/object:Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult
  data:
    kind: youtube#searchResult
    etag: ! '"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/dTOXDCV4PSk4woUH3RTDfYWH7sc"'
    id:
      kind: youtube#video
      videoId: cfuq0Qs4154
    snippet:
      publishedAt: '2015-06-29T02:05:19.000Z'
      channelId: UCH1vIUNu9z4hosPO4IiEDKg
      title: MY CUTE CAT VIDEO XD
      description: I MADE THIS VIDEO FOR FUN BECAUSE IT WOULD BE A CUTE FUN IDEAXD.
      thumbnails:
        default:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cfuq0Qs4154/default.jpg
        medium:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cfuq0Qs4154/mqdefault.jpg
        high:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cfuq0Qs4154/hqdefault.jpg
      channelTitle: Nlg31
      liveBroadcastContent: none
- !ruby/object:Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult
  data:
    kind: youtube#searchResult
    etag: ! '"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/3VF2zQBJ71Si2Zcar34cJGKDp6A"'
    id:
      kind: youtube#playlist
      playlistId: PLMPGTLYCAiq9gAh6UnpaXx_PtKENmh1P6
    snippet:
      publishedAt: '2015-06-29T01:52:34.000Z'
      channelId: UCl65ZDJ_D2QnvzknOzC_Syw
      title: Black Cat
      description: ''
      thumbnails:
        default:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UexNlx4mj1g/default.jpg
        medium:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UexNlx4mj1g/mqdefault.jpg
        high:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UexNlx4mj1g/hqdefault.jpg
      channelTitle: ''
      liveBroadcastContent: none
- !ruby/object:Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult
  data:
    kind: youtube#searchResult
    etag: ! '"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/nldPN_K-A-jNCqF0I3MlOjByOog"'
    id:
      kind: youtube#video
      videoId: INraypSN3Q0
    snippet:
      publishedAt: '2015-06-29T01:35:33.000Z'
      channelId: UCVbqIMbp2qRhK6-YXYkOF7g
      title: ! 'Aksi kucing dubsmash lucu.. #funny #cat #pet'
      description: Hilarious cats.
      thumbnails:
        default:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/INraypSN3Q0/default.jpg
        medium:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/INraypSN3Q0/mqdefault.jpg
        high:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/INraypSN3Q0/hqdefault.jpg
      channelTitle: ''
      liveBroadcastContent: none
- !ruby/object:Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::SearchResult
  data:
    kind: youtube#searchResult
    etag: ! '"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/2_PMO7FctA_79aqVhV0D83Yw7VY"'
    id:
      kind: youtube#video
      videoId: Bt6NgC0peLI
    snippet:
      publishedAt: '2015-06-29T01:06:00.000Z'
      channelId: UCpM_hmOVus872lSLIdbirXQ
      title: ! 'Conversation With a Cat: Should I Go Vegan?'
      description: I'm 80% vegan, but my cat won't hesitate to eat lizards/birds...
      thumbnails:
        default:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bt6NgC0peLI/default.jpg
        medium:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bt6NgC0peLI/mqdefault.jpg
        high:
          url: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bt6NgC0peLI/hqdefault.jpg
      channelTitle: LifeLibertyNow
      liveBroadcastContent: none
```

Answer (score 1):

It could simply be because the search result isn't returning video.

It means the search result `kind` it returned could be `youtube#playlist` or `youtube#channel` rather than `youtube#video`. In such cases you might want to check for `playlistId` or `channelId`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to clearly outline what is going wrong here is the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - Only talk to your immediate friends.

Which you don't need to slavishly obey but can often tell you when something is wrong with the system.

So when you do `video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url` you're not just violating the Law of Demeter - you're running it over repeatedly - with a truck.

So lets rewrite it:

```
@search_response = client.execute!(
  :api_method => youtube.search.list,
  :parameters => {
    :part => 'snippet',
    :q => 'cat',
    :maxResults => 10,
    :order => 'date',
    :pageToken => pageToken
  }
)

data = @search_response.data
@videos = @search_response.data.try(:items) || []
```

In your view

```
<% @videos.each do |video| %>
    <%- snippet = video.snippet -%>
    <%- if video.id -%>
    ID: <%= video.id.try(:videoId) %><br />
    <%- end ->
    <%- if snippet -%>
    Title: <%= snippet.title %><br />
    Description: <%= snippet.description %><br />
    <%- end -%> 
    <% 
    thumbnails = snippet.thumbnails
    if thumbnails %>
    <img src="<%= thumbnails.high.url %>" with="480" height="360">    
    <% end %>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
<% end %>
```

However to avoid making such a total mess you often want to normalize the responses you get from an API:

```
class Video
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :id
  attr_accessor :thumbnails
  attr_accessor :snippet
  attr_accessor :description
  attr_accessor :title

  def initialize(hash = {})
    @id = hash.try[:id].try(:videoId),
    @snippet = hash.try(:snippet),
    @thumbnails = hash.try(:snippet).try(:thumbnails),
    @description = hash.try(:snippet).try(:description)
    @title = hash.try(:snippet).try(:title)
  end
end
```

So you would do

```
@videos = @videos.map { |v| Video.new(v) }
```

And rewrite your view:

```
<% @videos.each do |video| %>
    ID: <%= video.id %><br />
    Title: <%= video.title %><br />
    Description: <%= video.description %><br />
    <% thumbnail = video.thumbnails.try(:high).try(:url) %>
    <% if thumbnail %>
    <img src="<%= thumbnail %>" with="480" height="360"><br />
    <% end %>
    <br />
    <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your answer but it still give the same error:( It's so weird because it indeed has videoId if I let it output the debug info just like above(I added more info in my question. please check)

Comment: Does it matter because videoId has capitalized character in it?

Comment: '<%= video.id.try(:videoId)' returns 'undefined method `videoId''

Comment: '<%= video.id.inspect %>' outputs 'ID: #<Google::APIClient::Schema::Youtube::V3::ResourceId:0xcab55e8 DATA:{"kind"=>"youtube#video", "videoId"=>"VOf3U6j6OHE"}>'  It has videoId in every single video. Why:(

Comment: I found a solution!!! '<%= video['id']['videoId']' works as well. Why is that....